# convert .data file to .csv

Tags: python, r, excel, csv

I have found the following data set named ecoli.data and available in:

https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/ecoli/

I would like to open it in R for making a classification task, but I would prefer to convert this document into a csv file. When I open it in word I notice that is not tab delimited, because there are like tree spaces between each row; so bottomline question is how to convert this file into csv using Excel or maybe Python.

Comment: Open in Excel as fixed width.  Save as CSV.

Comment: Fixed width is supported by [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#files-with-fixed-width-columns)

Answer (score 10):

Rename the file to `ecoli.txt` then open it in Excel. This way you will be using the "Text Import Wizard" of Microsoft Excel that enables you to chose options like "Fixed width". Just click on "next" a few times and "finish" and you will have the data in the Excel grid. Now save it again as CSV.

Answer (score 3):

Using Python 2.7:

```
import csv

with open('ecoli.data.txt') as input_file:
   lines = input_file.readlines()
   newLines = []
   for line in lines:
      newLine = line.strip().split()
      newLines.append( newLine )

with open('output.csv', 'wb') as test_file:
   file_writer = csv.writer(test_file)
   file_writer.writerows( newLines )
```

Answer (score 3):

Rename it in the file folder from

```
ecoli.data
```

to

```
ecoli.csv
```

Then you can use it in your code with the standard import code for csv, without any adding. No more to look back on it.
It worked for me with adult.data!

Answer (score 1):

Here are two ways to actually do that in R (that work):

```
library(readr)

url <- "https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/ecoli/ecoli.data"
```

with base R

```
df <- read.table(url)
dplyr::glimpse(df)

## Observations: 336
## Variables:
## $ V1 (fctr) AAT_ECOLI, ACEA_ECOLI, ACEK_ECOLI, ACKA_ECOLI, ADI_ECOLI, ...
## $ V2 (dbl) 0.49, 0.07, 0.56, 0.59, 0.23, 0.67, 0.29, 0.21, 0.20, 0.42,...
## $ V3 (dbl) 0.29, 0.40, 0.40, 0.49, 0.32, 0.39, 0.28, 0.34, 0.44, 0.40,...
## $ V4 (dbl) 0.48, 0.48, 0.48, 0.48, 0.48, 0.48, 0.48, 0.48, 0.48, 0.48,...
## $ V5 (dbl) 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5,...
## $ V6 (dbl) 0.56, 0.54, 0.49, 0.52, 0.55, 0.36, 0.44, 0.51, 0.46, 0.56,...
## $ V7 (dbl) 0.24, 0.35, 0.37, 0.45, 0.25, 0.38, 0.23, 0.28, 0.51, 0.18,...
## $ V8 (dbl) 0.35, 0.44, 0.46, 0.36, 0.35, 0.46, 0.34, 0.39, 0.57, 0.30,...
## $ V9 (fctr) cp, cp, cp, cp, cp, cp, cp, cp, cp, cp, cp, cp, cp, cp, cp...

write.csv(df, "ecoli.csv", row.names=FALSE)
```

with `readr` functions

```
df <- read_table(url, col_names=FALSE)
dplyr::glimpse(df)

## Observations: 336
## Variables:
## $ X1 (chr) "AAT_ECOLI", "ACEA_ECOLI", "ACEK_ECOLI", "ACKA_ECOLI", "ADI...
## $ X2 (dbl) 0.49, 0.07, 0.56, 0.59, 0.23, 0.67, 0.29, 0.21, 0.20, 0.42,...
## $ X3 (dbl) 0.29, 0.40, 0.40, 0.49, 0.32, 0.39, 0.28, 0.34, 0.44, 0.40,...
## $ X4 (dbl) 0.48, 0.48, 0.48, 0.48, 0.48, 0.48, 0.48, 0.48, 0.48, 0.48,...
## $ X5 (dbl) 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5,...
## $ X6 (dbl) 0.56, 0.54, 0.49, 0.52, 0.55, 0.36, 0.44, 0.51, 0.46, 0.56,...
## $ X7 (dbl) 0.24, 0.35, 0.37, 0.45, 0.25, 0.38, 0.23, 0.28, 0.51, 0.18,...
## $ X8 (dbl) 0.35, 0.44, 0.46, 0.36, 0.35, 0.46, 0.34, 0.39, 0.57, 0.30,...
## $ X9 (chr) "cp", "cp", "cp", "cp", "cp", "cp", "cp", "cp", "cp", "cp",...

write_csv(df, "ecoli.csv")
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
pandas.read_table('https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/ecoli/', delim_whitespace=True)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way I got, is just renaming the file from `ecoli.data` to `ecoli.csv`, but not in PC. Rename in your mobile. It will automatically convert the extension.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to solve your problem could be to read your `.data` file on R using the `read.table` command.

```
ecoli <- read.table("ecoli.data",header=F)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Window Power shell command,

cat german.data | %{$_ -replace " ",","} | sc german.csv

Using UXIX SED command,

sed 's/ /,/g' german.data > german.csv

Answer (score 0):

You can use Pandas library for this conversion.
import pandas as pd

## Read the .data file into a pandas DataFrame

df = pd.read_csv('your_data_file.data', header=None)

## Save the DataFrame to a CSV file

df.to_csv('output_file.csv', index=False)

Attention: You may face OSError during this process.
One of the good solutions is just to replace backslashes with forwarding slash.
Reference for this tip:https://www.pythonpool.com/oserror-errno22-invalid-argument-solved/

Answer (score -1):

It's very simple, click the actual dataset name ex: xyz.data and rename it with XYZ.csv this will be converted into CSV format.